# open .exe file in specific size via python

Tags: python, winapi, process, window, size

I'm trying to create a button that can open a program in a specific size using win32process. 
somehow the code I wrote is not working.. 
how do I make this work?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import win32process


window=Tk()

def openfile():
    window.filename = askopenfilename(title="Open file", filetypes=(("exe files", "*.exe"),("all files", "*.*")))  
    startupinfo = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwX = 10
    startupinfo.dwY = 20
    startupinfo.dwXSize = 600
    startupinfo.dwYSize = 100

    win32process.CreateProcess(
        None,
        window.filename,
        None,
        None,
        False,
        0,
        None,
        None,
        startupinfo
    )

OpeButton = Button(window, text="Open", command=openfile)#COMMAND=OPEN
OpeButton.pack()
OpeButton.place(relx = 0.52, rely = 0.5)

window.overrideredirect(1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Van you change the window size manually after starting up the program by hand?

I'm asking as not all programs allow resizing to all sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the `dwFlags` field of the `STARTUPINFO`, so the `dwX`/`dwY` and `dwXSize`/`dwYSize` fields will be ignored. You need to add these flags to use those fields:

```py
startupinfo.dwFlags = win32process.STARTF_USEPOSITION | win32process.STARTF_USESIZE
```

However, this is still not a guarantee that the target window will actually be in the specified position and size. It is up to the target process to decide for itself whether it will honor the `STARTUPINFO` or not.