# Is there a way to alter the size and position of a window after opening it through tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code so far:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

system_properties=("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\System Information.lnk")
device_manager=("devmgmt.msc")

root = Tk()

#root.title()

window = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("200x200")

def open_app():
    os.startfile(system_properties)
    os.system(device_manager)

Button(root, text ='Open', 
       command = open_app).pack(side = TOP, 
                                 pady = 10) 

root.mainloop()
```

To clarify I am not looking to change the tkinter window. What I want to do is open multiple applications at once on Windows 11 with no overlap like in a split screen format, but I am not sure how to incorporate code to make the windows display with my desired size and position. Currently, they are opening on top of each other with different window sizes.

Comment: If I understood right, this library could help you with what you are trying to do : **win32process**, one example I came across : **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238946/open-exe-file-in-specific-size-via-python** it is for an exe file, however you should be able to find the same for your apps.

Comment: This question isn't very clear.  You asked "Is there a way to alter the size and position of a window after opening it through tkinter?" You can drag windows around and change their size with the mouse.  Are you asking how to control the size and position of a tkinter window when it is created? If that is what you are interested in then [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910858/how-to-specify-where-a-tkinter-window-opens)